# Implementing an Interface with Child Classes

Tags: vb.net, oop, interface, inheritance

I have the following interfaces:

```
Interface IViewModel
    ...
End Interface

Interface ISpecialViewModel
    Inherits IViewModel
    ...
End Interface

Interface IView
    WriteOnly Property MyViewModel As IViewModel
End Interface
```

Following are my classes:

```
Class VerySpecialViewModel
    implements ISpecialViewModel
    ...
End Class

Class View
    Implements IView

    Public WriteOnly Property MyViewModel As VerySpecialViewModel Implements IView.MyViewModel 
        ...
    End Property
End Class
```

It tells me that 'MyViewModel' cannot implement 'MyViewModel' because there is no matching property on interface 'IView'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Interface ISomething
    WriteOnly Property Prop As IParent
End Interface
```

That interface declaration isn't satisfied by your class implementation. Consider following situation:

There is another interface called IChild2:

```
Public Interface IChild2
    Inherits IParent
    ...
End Interface
```

According to `ISomething` interface you should be able to assign instance of class implementing `IChild2` into `Thing.Prop`, because it inherits `IParent`.But you can't, because `Thing.Prop` property is of `IChild` type and `IChild2` does not inherits `IChild`

***Update***

What about that solution:

```
Class ThingBase
    Implements ISomething

    Public WriteOnly Property Prop As IParent Implements ISomething.Prop
        Set(value As IParent)

        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Class Thing
    Inherits ThingBase

    Public Overloads WriteOnly Property Prop As IChild
        Set(value As IChild)
            MyBase.Prop = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

***Update2***

```
Interface IView(Of T As IViewModel)
    WriteOnly Property MyViewModel As T
End Interface

Class VerySpecialViewModel
    Implements ISpecialViewModel
End Class

Class View
    Implements IView(Of ISpecialViewModel)

    Public WriteOnly Property MyViewModel As ISpecialViewModel Implements IView(Of ISpecialViewModel).MyViewModel
        Set(value As ISpecialViewModel)

        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

*or*

```
Class View
    Implements IView(Of VerySpecialViewModel)

    Public WriteOnly Property MyViewModel As VerySpecialViewModel Implements IView(Of VerySpecialViewModel).MyViewModel
        Set(value As VerySpecialViewModel)

        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: hmmm... I see. Is there an elegant solution around it?

Comment: Around what? Around implementing interface without satisfying its definition? Not really.

Comment: This is MVVM. I'm basically trying to implement a common interface IParent on all my ViewModels. Some of these ViewModels are more specialized and implement IChild. Similarly my Views also implement a common interface ISomething, which has a member Prop pointing to the underlying ViewModel class. Now I'm not sure what type this Prop be in ISomething? My idea was for it to be of IParent type, so that all Views could implement it.

Comment: See my update. You should create `ThingBase` class or use generics.

Comment: Excellent solution. The only issue is that my View already inherits from a Framework class and vb.net doesn't allow multiple inheritence.

Comment: Generics...mmmm...let me think.

Comment: Gem of a solution. Thanks a bunch.