# Why is not possible to cast IView(Of SpecificViewModel) to IView(Of ViewModelBase)?

Tags: vb.net, generics, mvvm, interface, casting

This is MVVM + WPF, but really doesn't have much to do with those tools. The problem is more generic and belongs to OO design.

Yesterday MarcinJuraszek helped me by suggesting an excellent solution to the [original problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15379057/implementing-an-interface-with-child-classes/15379126#15379126). That solution fixed the problem at hand, but now I'm stuck at the next level. Here's how it goes:

**ViewModels**

My ViewModel classes inherit from a common abstract parent ViewModel class:

```
Public MustInherit Class ViewModelBase
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable

    ...

End Class
```

Concrete ViewModels go like this:

```
Class SalesOrderEntryViewModel
    Inherits ViewModelBase
    Implements IEditorViewModel, IChildViewModel

    ...

End Class
```

`IEditorViewModel` and `IChildViewModel` are interfaces that some of my concrete ViewModels implement.

**Views**

All my View classes implement the following interface:

```
Interface IView(Of T As ViewModelBase)
    WriteOnly Property MyVM As T
    ReadOnly Property HeaderText As String
End Interface
```

A concrete View that is based on the `SalesOrderEntryViewModel` I described above is defined as:

```
Class SalesOrderEntryPage
    Implements IView(Of SalesOrderEntryViewModel)

End Class
```

So far so good. The actual problem I'm facing now is that I want to create a strongly typed collection of all my open Views at application level. What should be the type of this collection? I tried something like the following:

```
Dim Views As List(Of IView(Of ViewModelBase))
```

When I try to add an object of `SalesOrderEntryPage` class to this list, it throws a run-time exception telling me that it cannot convert from `SalesOrderEntryPage` to `IView(Of ViewModelBase)`, although looking at the definitions, `SalesOrderEntryPage` really is an `IView(Of ViewModelBase)`.

For now, VB.NET is helping me out with late-binding, but am wondering why it says so and what is an elegant solution in this regard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are facing is related to the use of generics, and has to do with a concept called *variance* of the generic type parameter. The type parameter of a generic interface can be *invariant*, *covariant* or *contravariant*.

By default, you generic interface is invariant in it's type T. This means, that you can use T as the type for parameters of methods and as a return type of methods as well. On the downside, this means that neither of the following is possible:

> Cast IView(Of ViewModelBase) to IView(Of SalesOrderEntryViewModel)
>
> Cast IView(Of SalesOrderEntryViewModel) to IView(Of ViewModelBase)

This makes sense, when you consider:

---

1. Supposed `IView(Of T)` has a method which requires **a parameter of type** `T`: This means, that `IView(Of SalesOrderEntryViewModel)` has a method, which requires a parameter of type `SalesOrderEntryViewModel`. But if you could cast `IView(Of SalesOrderEntryViewModel)` to `IView(Of ViewModelBase)`, you would expect it to have a method with a parameter of type `ViewModelBase`, but it hasn't, because the method is designed for parameters of type `SalesOrderEntryViewModel` only and not of its generalized versions or other ViewModels which derive from `ViewModelBase`. The result: **You cannot cast IView(Of SalesOrderEntryViewModel) to IView(Of ViewModelBase).**

---

1. Supposed `IView(Of T)` has a method which **returns a value of type T** and suppose a method on a class which implements `IView(Of ViewModelBase)` would return a `SalesOrderEntryViewModel`, which is ok because `SalesOrderEntryViewModel` is an instance of `ViewModelBase`. SO far so good. But if you now try to cast this class to `IView(Of SomeOtherViewModel`, it doesn't work anymore, because the type your method wants to return `SalesOrderEntryViewModel` is not an instance of `SomeOtherViewModel`. The result: **You cannot cast IView(Of ViewModelBase) to IView(Of SalesOrderEntryViewModel).**

---

But:

There is a way around one of these constraints, but you have to choose:

You can make your interface *contravariant* in `T`: This means, that you cannot use T as a return type for your methods, but you can cast `Interface(Of Base)` to `Interface(Of Derived)`.

```
Interface IContravariant(Of In A)
    Sub SetSomething(ByVal sampleArg As A)
    Sub DoSomething(Of T As A)()
    ' The following statement generates a compiler error. 
    ' Function GetSomething() As A 
End Interface
```

Or you make your interface *covariant* in `T`: Then you cannot have methods which take parameters of type `T`, but you can cast `Interface(Of Derived)` to `Interface(Of Base)`.

```
Interface ICovariant(Of Out R)
    ' The following statement generates a compiler error 
    ' because you can use only contravariant or invariant types 
    ' in generic contstraints. 
    ' Sub DoSomething(Of T As R)() 
End Interface
```

That's the theory.

---

**For your special case:**

> When I try to add an object of SalesOrderEntryPage class to this list,
>   it throws a run-time exception telling me that it cannot convert from
>   SalesOrderEntryPage to IView(Of ViewModelBase)

So, you want to cast from interface(Of Derived) to Interface(Of Base). This means, you need to make your interface `IView` covariant in its ViewModelType. Therefore you loose the ability to set the ViewModel via your `IView` interface.

So, it doesn't really solve the problem, but I hope it makes clear to you, why it is not working, what you're trying to do.

I would suggest defining a contravariant or nongeneric base interface for all your Views. I did the latter and although it doesn't contain much (the nongeneric IView(Model) interface), it makes life a lot easier. Then derive an interface which allows setting the ViewModel of your View. This way you can fill your collections with the `readonly` versions of your Views.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. The problem is that my generic parameter is being used to define a property (both Get and Set) in my ViewModel classes, so from what I have understood from your answer is that I need both co- and contra-variant behavior at the same time, which as I understand is not possible. I ended up doing Reflection for this purpose. Will post it shortly. But this is definitely the correct answer for the general case.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who gets trapped in this situation and is willing to do Reflection, here's a helper method that uses Reflection information to achieve this:

```
    Private Function ImplementsGenericInterface(type As Type, interfaceName As String, genericArgTypeName As String) As Boolean
    Dim myFilter As New Reflection.TypeFilter(Function(typeObj As Type, criteriaObj As [Object])
                                                  Return typeObj.ToString().StartsWith(interfaceName)
                                              End Function)

    Dim MyIViewInterfaces() As System.[Type] = type.FindInterfaces(myFilter, "")

    If MyIViewInterfaces.Length > 0 Then
        Return MyIViewInterfaces.Any(Function(x) x.GetGenericArguments().Any(Function(y) y.BaseType.Name = genericArgTypeName))
    End If

    Return False
End Function
```

For the example I posted in the question, use it like this:

```
ImplementsGenericInterface(objSalesOrderEntryPage.GetType(), "ProjectNamespace. Name", GetType(ViewModelBase).Name)
```